# Lubuntu: How do I autostart xfce4 power manager?

Tags: lubuntu, autostart, xfce4-power-manager

I just upgraded my 64 bit Lubuntu to 13.10 on my netbook today. After the upgrade, I simply can't autostart the xfce4 power manager. I tried to add from the desktop session settings, I tried to copy the power manager.desktop file to `~/.config/autostart` folder.

Everything looks fine. Then I logout, log back in and the darn power manager just won't start automatically. It only starts when I double click the icon, or if I start it from the terminal.

Comment: I tried to autostart Firefox, that's not working either, so the prblem is with the autostart, not with the specific app.

Comment: Perhaps this Bug: [xfce4-power-manager is not running by default with Lubuntu 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1242452)

Answer (score 8):

Check `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`.

Look for laptop_mode and see that it's set to 'yes':

```
[State]
laptop_mode=yes
```

This worked for me at least. Mine was set to 'no' so I would have to start xfce4-power-manager manually. By changing the value to 'yes' it now starts at login automatically without any further configuration.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for me in 13.10.

Answer (score 8):

Either:

1. Open Preferences → Default applications for LXSession.
2. Go to the autostart tab.
3. Change the option "Disable autostarted applications" from `config-only` to `no`.

---

Or similarly:

1. Edit `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`
2. Change the following line under `[Session]`
3. Change

   ```
   disable_autostart=config-only
   ```

   to this instead:

   ```
   disable_autostart=no
   ```

Comment: Very nice! Is there any documentation? I didn't come across any for "Default applications for LXSession".

Comment: Also see https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-September/005577.html

Comment: Yes, it's more safe to use UX instead of editing files manually! And to understand what's happening behind the scene in parallel!

Answer (score 2):

there's sth. wrong in the autostart-entry of the power-manager. That makes it only work in XFCE (e.g. Xubuntu), but not LXDE/Lubuntu

in a Terminal type

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop
```

Go to the line saying:

```
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

and comment it out

```
#OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

exit the editor with Ctrl-O (save) and Ctrl-X (exit)

In your next session power manager should start automatically

Comment: 6 years later (Lubuntu 20), there's a line instead that reads `NotShowIn=GNOME;KDE;Unity;MATE;LXQt;`. LXQt is the Lubuntu desktop. Simply remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, for some applications it can be useful to instead of starting them directly, to use a script which delays the starting of the program.

Create a file like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
xfce-power-manager
```

And save it as powermanagerautostart.sh somewhere safe, I use a folder called /home/shane/scripts.

Then instead of adding xfce-power-manager to desktop session settings, add

```
bash /home/username/scripts/powermanagerautostart.sh
```

This may fix your problem.

Comment: I tried it, I made that script, I executed it, it works. After that I realized, that I can't add a script like that to desktop session settings in an LXDE environment, like in gnome. So I made a .desktop file /,that launches the script/, in the ~/.config/autostart folder. Than I double clicked the .desktop file, an it brought up the xfce4 power manager. But after I logged out, and logged back in, it still does NOT work automatically :(

Answer (score 0):

1. create a file .starter in your home dir and make it executable
2. in that file write command: cairo-dock, save and close
3. edit file: sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
4. add this new line: @/home/user/.starter #user is you
5. save and close
6. reboot and it shall now run automaticaly

p.s. sorry I am talking about autostarting cairo, but same procedure should work for you, you only have to know the starting command. same way I start dropbox, conky, compton in lubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

I edited `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf` and changed the following line under `[Session]` from :

```
disable_autostart=config-only
```

to this instead:

```
disable_autostart=no
```

Worked for me on my netbook as suggested by MrQuade.

Answer (score 0):

In lubuntu not working xfce4 power manager:

1. uninstall xfce4 power manager (optional)
2. install gnome-power-manager
3. Desktop session setting enable (Demonio de configuración de Gnome)(Gnome settings daemon)
4. Dconf editor `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power` (modify at will)

the problem I found is that when you activate the gnome daemon status bar could not put it on transparent

Fix it with `dconf / org / gnome / desktop / bakground (off draw-background)`

sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

xfce4-power-manager not started, applet not visible

Delete > Desktop configuration file:

/etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop

Settings Manager / Session and Startup / Startup Applications

Item disabled:

```
Energy Management (power Management Xfce environment)
```

New item enabled with new command:

```
Mame:          Xfce Power Manager (For example-Your name)
Description:   Power manager startup
Command:       xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon
```

http://ubuntuset.url.ph/power_manager.html