# Lubuntu 14.04: Cannot start Power Manager

Tags: lubuntu, power-management, xfce, lxde, xfce4-power-manager

I recently installed the Lubuntu Desktop and I can't start the Power Manager. It returns the question:

`Xfce4 Power Manager is not running, do you want to launch it now?`

but when I click `Run`, it does nothing.

Running `xfce4-power-manager` from the terminal, even as superuser (i.e. `sudo xfce4-power-manager`), does absolutely nothing. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal behavior of `xfce4-power-manager`, if you get **no response** after you run this command the process is started. You can check it with this command:

```
ps aux | awk -v s="xfce4-power-manager" 'NR>1 && $11~s'
```

the output should be something like this:

```
username      8223  0.0  0.8  33344  4148 ?        Ssl  10:23   0:00 xfce4-power-manager
```

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/485436/265974))

If you want to change the settings of the xfce4-power-manager you have to run:

`xfce4-power-manager-settings`

or

`xfce4-power-manager --customize`

But its not normal that `xfce4-power-manager`does not autostart...

To autostart xfce4-power-manager this should help: [Lubuntu: How do I autostart xfce4 power manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360520/lubuntu-how-do-i-autostart-xfce4-power-manager)

This could be also helpfull : [xfce4-power-manager is not running by default with Lubuntu 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1242452)  (Bug)